# Free Return Transfer Problem

Tags: orbital-mechanics, gravity-assist, free-return

I'm trying to understand how a free-transfer return works.

It makes sense to me conceptually, but putting numbers to it it is unclear.

I'm not sure how to obtain information about the transfer ellipse.

For example, with a Transfer Angle of 173.50 degrees and an Earth parking orbit of 195km, I cannot figure out the velocity of the spacecraft leaving Earth to reach the moon.

Normally I would get the Semi-Major Axis of the transfer ellipse (and from here calculate the velocities), but since this ellipse doesn't have an apoapsis at the Moon (i.e. the ellipse is larger), I don't know how to gain any additional information from this scenario.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at all of the answers to [How does Exploration Mission 1 orbit differ from Apollo-era free-return? How far from Earth (and Moon) does it go?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/21095/12102) and [Lunar Free Return Trajectory Simulation](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/20151/12102) and [Totally Non-elliptic Rocket Path](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/21811/12102) and especially [Is a solar free-return trajectory possible?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/35129/12102)

Comment: It's possible that none of these may answer your question *for you,* but some things might help you be able to point at something specific that jumps out at you that you'd like clarified.